# Call Stored Procedure in Grails (Step by step)

Tags: grails, grails-controller

Can anyone tell me how to call stored procedure from Grails which is present in User-defined path.

Comment: What do you mean by user defined path? Stored procedures are stored on sql server. You want to execute a sql file stored on a file system ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For that purpose you can use `Groovy Sql`.

To use Groovy SQL:

1. `import groovy.sql.Sql`
2. Request a reference to the datasource with `def dataSource` or `def sessionFactory` for transactions
3. Create an Sql object using `def sql = new Sql(dataSource)` or `def sql = new Sql(sessionFactory.currentSession.connection())`
4. Use Groovy SQL as required

Grails will manage the connection to the datasource automatically.

Note: `dataSource` and `sessionFactory` are beans that you would have to inject in your pojo/bean class.

So to execute sql code written on your file:

```
String sqlFilePath = grailsApplication.parentContext.servletContext.getRealPath("/data/proc.sql")
String sqlString = new File(sqlFilePath).text

Sql sql = new Sql(sessionFactory.currentSession.connection())
sql.execute(sqlString)
```

This will execute any sql statements written in your file on your sql server.

Comment: String sql= SELECT * FROM acc_project_setup aps  WHERE 1=1 :projectQuery 
    This is my main Query in dummy.sql file, i want to pass :projectQuery string param in this file. I tried  to pass params using Map like below but don't execute.
  String projectQuery = "AND ajd.project_id=1"  StringsqlFilePath=Holders.grailsApplication.mainContext.getResource("/path/to/file/"+ "dummy.sql").file.getAbsoluteFile()
    def sqlString = new File(sqlFilePath).text
     Sql sql = new Sql(dataSource)
      sql.rows(sqlString, [projectQuery : projectQuery])
     ERROR: syntax error at or near "$1"

Answer (score 0):

From JDriven's blog post [Grails Goodness: Using Hibernate Native SQL Queries](https://blog.jdriven.com/2014/03/grails-goodness-using-hibernate-native-sql-queries/):

> In the following sample we create a new Grails service and use a
> Hibernate native SQL query to execute a selectable stored procedure
> with the name `organisation_breadcrumbs`. This stored procedure takes
> one argument `startId` and will return a list of results with an id,
> name and level column.
>
> ```scala
> class OrganisationService {
>
>     // Auto inject SessionFactory we can use
>     // to get the current Hibernate session.
>     def sessionFactory
>
>     List breadcrumbs(final Long startOrganisationId) {
>
>         // Get the current Hiberante session.
>         final session = sessionFactory.currentSession
>
>         // Query string with :startId as parameter placeholder.
>         final String query = 'select id, name, level from organisation_breadcrumbs(:startId) order by level desc'
>
>         // Create native SQL query.
>         final sqlQuery = session.createSQLQuery(query)
>
>         // Use Groovy with() method to invoke multiple methods
>         // on the sqlQuery object.
>         final results = sqlQuery.with {
>             // Set domain class as entity.
>             // Properties in domain class id, name, level will
>             // be automatically filled.
>             addEntity(Organisation)
>
>             // Set value for parameter startId.
>             setLong('startId', startOrganisationId)
>
>             // Get all results.
>             list()
>         }
>         results
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> In the sample code we use the `addEntity()` method to map the query
> results to the domain class `Organisation`. To transform the results
> from a query to other objects we can use the `setResultTransformer()`
> method.
>
> Hibernate (and therefore Grails if we use the Hibernate plugin)
> already has a set of transformers we can use. For example, with the
> `org.hibernate.transform.AliasToEntityMapResultTransformer` (in place of `addEntity`) each result row is transformed into a Map where the column aliases are the keys of the map.
>
> ```java
> resultTransformer = AliasToEntityMapResultTransformer.INSTANCE
> ```